# Is Google loader still supported by Google?

Tags: jquery, google-loader

I'd like to use google loader in a project but within the google loader script, the latest version of jquery they are using is version 1.7.1. That version came out like 3 years ago.

https://developers.google.com/loader/

The bottom of the page says last updated on "January 8, 2014". Is it still supported? And yes, I know how to link directly to libraries using their CDN. I just have a particular use for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted an up to date version of google loader so I got the original, pretty printed it, added the latest versions of jquery and removed all the cruft (frameworks I wasn't using like scriptaculous, etc.) and then re-minified it.

Here is the finished version that supports jquery 1.11.0 and 2.1.0

https://github.com/nickfox/custom-google-loader

Feel free to grab it if you need it. If you have any questions about it, let me know.

To use it, just install it on your website and add the script like this:

```
<script src="custom-google-loader-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

and call it like this:

```
google.load('jquery', '1.11.0');
```

or this for maps:

```
google.load('maps', '3', {
    other_params: 'sensor=false&libraries=adsense'
});
```

If anyone from Google can answer the original question, or better yet, update your version of google loader, that would be great.