# Modern google loader not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, svg

I've been trying to find a modern google loader which is cross browser.
Can anyone please help me find one, i found this one which works for all except Internet Explorer, or maybe tell me how i can get this one to work in IE ?
I tried fakesmile but it didnt work.

HTML :

```
    <div class="loader">
    <svg class="circular">
        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
  .loader {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        zoom: 1;
    }

    .circular {
        animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
    }


    .path {
        stroke: gray;
        stroke-dasharray: 1,200;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
        stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes dash {
        0% {
            stroke-dasharray: 1,200;
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }

        50% {
            stroke-dasharray: 89,200;
            stroke-dashoffset: -35;
        }

        100% {
            stroke-dasharray: 89,200;
            stroke-dashoffset: -124;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the version of IE you want to support?

Comment: This is your code as a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prqk1gby/.  It appears to work for chrome so as @JacobGray stated, you've likely to have hit a browser compatibility issue and need to specify how far back you want to go for IE.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for your response, a recent IE like 11 or Edge would be fine, but it's not working in any of them :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Google loader still supported by Google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603820/is-google-loader-still-supported-by-google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of IE do not support the keyframes, i left IE behind.